Not all XCF files are getting thumbnails
I've done some searching, but not many people seem to have this exact problem. So am I doing something wrong?
The problem is: XCF files that were written by GIMP with the "Save this XCF file with better but slower compression" option do not have thumbnails visible in the file manager. Files saved without this option are all right.
So in other words, saving the same image twice, once with the option, looks like this in Dolphin:

So the "better but slower" image has the generic icon, while the other one has the thumbnail I'd expect for both of them.
This difference is present in all file managers and in all windows that show previews, like the "Open" dialog in graphics programs, even in GIMP itself.
So what goes wrong? I tried searching on the web, but nobody seems to have this exact same problem. On the web it's always all XCF files having problems, and the solution usually being to install kdegraphics-thumbnailers. But I already have that and I'm not sure what to try now.
This is with GIMP 2.10.34, Linux 6.1.0, Debian 12, KDE Plasma 5.27.5 and no backports installed.
